# React hook useState with array cause missing render calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have following code:

```
function MyComponent( props ) {
    let arrSize = 5;
    const [arr, setArr] = useState( () => {
        let initial = new Array(arrSize);
        for(let i=0; i<arrSize; i++) initial.push({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
        return initial;
    });

    mouseEventCallback = (e) => {
        // ...
        let tmp = arr;
        // ...
        setArr( tmp );
    }

    let cmp = [];
    for(let i=0; i<arrSize; i++) {  
       cmp.push( <span key={i} className={arr[i].foo}></span> );
    }

    return (
        <div>
           {cmp}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And when mouse callback called a few times, i have a problem: state params changed ok(inspecting tab in Chrome web browser with react components), but DOM elements with this state not all rerendered - some of them has old state.

When i add dummy state - all works perfect:

```
function MyComponent( props ) {
    let arrSize = 5;
    const [arr, setArr] = useState( () => {
        let initial = new Array(arrSize);
        for(let i=0; i<arrSize; i++) initial.push({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
        return initial;
    });
    const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(0);

    mouseEventCallback = (e) => {
        // ...
        let tmp = arr;
        // ...
        setArr( tmp );
        setDummy( Math.rand() );
    }

    let cmp = [];
    for(let i=0; i<arrSize; i++) {  
       cmp.push( <span key={i} className={arr[i].foo}></span> );
    }

    return (
        <div dataTest={dummy}>
           {cmp}
        </div>
    )
}
```

How i can improve my code and resolve my problem with right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component does not re-render upon setArr(tmp) because "tmp" variable references the same array as "arr" variable. Same reference means they point to the same thing in memory so when react performs comparison between old state and new state they return the same thing i.e. tmp === arr returns true. If old state = new state component does not re-render. So in order to re-render; make "tmp" point to a new array with the same data as "arr". You can use the ES6 spread operator.

Change: let tmp = arr;
To: **let tmp = [...arr];**

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a;
let c = [...a]; // ES6 Spread Operator

a === b; // returns true
a === c; // returns false
```

**Correct Code:**

```
function MyComponent( props ) {
    let arrSize = 5;
    const [arr, setArr] = useState( () => {
        let initial = new Array(arrSize);
        for(let i=0; i<arrSize; i++) initial.push({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
        return initial;
    });

    mouseEventCallback = (e) => {
        // ...
        let tmp = [...arr];
        // ...
        setArr( tmp );
    }

    let cmp = [];
    for(let i=0; i<arrSize; i++) {  
        cmp.push( <span key={i} className={arr[i].foo}></span> );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {cmp}
        </div>
    )
}
```